Gnosis Safe executeTransaction "missing revert data"
I'm triying to add a second confirmation and execute a safe transaction using gnosis safe sdk. The safe address is a 2/n.
`export async function signTransactionAndExecute(chainId, rpcUrlProvider, safeTxHash) {
try {
    let provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(rpcUrlProvider);
    let signer = new ethers.Wallet(safeSignerPK, provider);
    const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({ ethers, signerOrProvider: signer });
    const safeSdk = await Safe.default.create({ ethAdapter, signer });
    const apiKit = new SafeApiKit.default({
        chainId: BigInt(chainId)
    });

    const signature = await safeSdk.signTransactionHash(safeTxHash)
    console.log('Transaction signed')
    const response = await apiKit.confirmTransaction(safeTxHash, signature.data)
    console.log('Transaction confirmed')

    const safeTransaction = await apiKit.getTransaction(safeTxHash)
    console.log('Transaction fetched: ', safeTransaction)
   
    const executeTxResponse = await safeSdk.executeTransaction(safeTransaction, { nonce: safeTransaction.nonce })
    const receipt = await executeTxResponse.transactionResponse?.wait()

    console.log('Transaction executed')

    return receipt;
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error executing transaction:', error);
}

}`
With that code I can successfully add the second confirmation I need. In the UI I can see that the option to execute is available but I always get this error:
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  action: 'call',
  data: null,
  reason: null,
  transaction: {
    to: '0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E',
    data: '0xa0e67e2b',
    from: '0x254bCf789A047CAdc1fc7199c481983F84036492'
  },
  invocation: null,
  revert: null,
  shortMessage: 'missing revert data',
  info: {
    error: { message: 'invalid opcode: INVALID', code: -32000 },
    payload: { method: 'eth_call', params: [Array], id: 22, jsonrpc: '2.0' }
  }
}

The value of safeTransaction is:
   "safe":"0x50f7D2C5cab2bE90279b157bdC4E5547562Ad44B",
   "to":"0xaf88d065e77c8cC2239327C5EDb3A432268e5831",
   "value":"0",
   "data":"0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000254bcf789a047cadc1fc7199c481983f840364920000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005a55",
   "operation":0,
   "gasToken":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   "safeTxGas":0,
   "baseGas":0,
   "gasPrice":"0",
   "refundReceiver":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   "nonce":2,
   "executionDate":null,
   "submissionDate":"2024-07-01T20:48:13.384563Z",
   "modified":"2024-07-01T20:50:11.173036Z",
   "blockNumber":null,
   "transactionHash":null,
   "safeTxHash":"0x09389b3f5060262edda362f8068bfb77c2377fb3de4aff7c2a2a37902140aa44",
   "proposer":"0xfD97c83b1563cBF92022d47e9966Ea8c24AE7393",
   "executor":null,
   "isExecuted":false,
   "isSuccessful":null,
   "ethGasPrice":null,
   "maxFeePerGas":null,
   "maxPriorityFeePerGas":null,
   "gasUsed":null,
   "fee":null,
   "origin":"BTCUSD",
   "dataDecoded":{
      "method":"transfer",
      "parameters":[
         [
            "Object"
         ],
         [
            "Object"
         ]
      ]
   },
   "confirmationsRequired":2,
   "confirmations":[
      {
         "owner":"0xfD97c83b1563cBF92022d47e9966Ea8c24AE7393",
         "submissionDate":"2024-07-01T20:48:13.428709Z",
         "transactionHash":null,
         "signature":"0x8bfcdbe38e3c777770a9d1c6b7d0be003dc58d9d230ba5ba6138bd6a0a9a189e5b804c231bd75e89c8da368b6e0cbea293c0fe5cbb35b4a9ad6823820b1a770c1f",
         "signatureType":"ETH_SIGN"
      },
      {
         "owner":"0x254bCf789A047CAdc1fc7199c481983F84036492",
         "submissionDate":"2024-07-01T20:50:11.173036Z",
         "transactionHash":null,
         "signature":"0xf76d0189649d99b044d5bc36a576fd017d53912d9e8ed4386e12b4c7ad2a5e78503b9335a0206d67508c871c0ed8fd04fea64a59f066046848b34ba1082866831f",
         "signatureType":"ETH_SIGN"
      }
   ],
   "trusted":true,
   "signatures":null
}

I have been struggling with this for several hours and I haven't been able to make it work. Any help would be really appreaciated.
"@safe-global/api-kit": "^2.0.0",
"@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^2.0.0",
"@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "^2.0.0",

